# "Cookie Clicker Alpha" solution

Tags: clojure

I am trying to learn Clojure for some time. In my experience, it has been rather too easy to produce write-only code.

Here is a solution to [a simple problem](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2974486/dashboard#s=p1) with very little essential complexity. Input and output formats are extremely simple, too. Which means all complexity in it must be accidental. How to improve its legibility, intelligibility?

- Is the decomposition of the problem into functions all right?

Also other specific problems:

- How to input/output numbers? Is there any benefit to use `read-string` instead of `Double/parseDouble`? How to format floating point numbers to fixed precision without messing with the default locale?
- How to avoid the explicit `loop`/`recur`, which is currently a translation of a while loop?
- Are there definitions that should/shouldn't have bee private/dynamic?

> **Problem**
>
> You start with 0 cookies. You gain cookies at a rate
>   of 2 cookies per second [...]. Any time you
>   have at least **C** cookies, you can buy a cookie farm. Every time you buy
>   a cookie farm, it costs you **C** cookies and gives you an extra **F** cookies
>   per second.
>
> Once you have **X** cookies that you haven't spent on farms, you win!
>   Figure out how long it will take you to win if you use the best
>   possible strategy.

```
(ns cookie-clicker
  (:use [clojure.string :only [split]])
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [clojure.test :refer :all]))

;;See http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2974486/dashboard#s=p1

(defn parse-double [s] (java.lang.Double/parseDouble s))

(defn parse-row [line] 
  (map parse-double (split line #"\s+")))

(defn parse-test-cases [rdr]
  (->> rdr
    line-seq
    rest
    (map parse-row)))

(def initial-rate 2.0)

(defn min-time [c f x]
  (loop [n 0 ; no of factories used
         tc 0 ; time cost of factories built
         r initial-rate ; cookie production rate
         t (/ x r)] ; total time
    (let [n2 (inc n)
          tc2 (+ tc (/ c r))
          r2 (+ r f)
          t2 (+ tc2 (/ x r2))]
      (if (> t2 t) 
        t
        (recur n2 tc2 r2 t2)))))

(java.util.Locale/setDefault (java.util.Locale/US))

(defn ans [n t]
  (str "Case #" n ": " (format "%.7f" t))) 

(defn answers [test-cases]
  (map #(ans %1 (apply min-time %2)) 
       (rest (range))
       test-cases))

(defn spit-answers [in-file]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader in-file)]
    (doseq [answer (answers (parse-test-cases rdr))]
      (println answer))))

(defn solve [in-file out-file]
  (with-open [w (io/writer out-file :append false)]
    (binding [*out* w]
      (spit-answers in-file))))

(def ^:dynamic *tolerance* 1e-6)

(defn- within-tolerance [expected actual] 
  (< (java.lang.Math/abs (- expected actual)) 
     *tolerance*))

(deftest case-3 
    (is (within-tolerance 
          63.9680013
          (min-time 30.50000 3.14159 1999.19990))))

(defn -main []
  (solve "resources/cookie_clicker/B-large-practice.in" 
         "resources/cookie_clicker/B-large-practice.out"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to admit, the actual "solving the problem" component of this is a little over my head. But, I thought I'd try to answer your questions and give you some style/structure feedback, for what it's worth :)

You can simplify your `ns` declaration like this:

```
(ns cookie-clicker
  (:require [clojure.string :refer (split)]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [clojure.test :refer :all]))
```

(`:require foo :refer (bar)` does the same thing as `:use foo :only (bar)`, and is generally considered preferable, especially as an alternative to having both `:use` and `:require` in your `ns` declaration)

I think `Double/parseDouble` is a good approach to parsing doubles in string form. `Integer/parseInt` is usually my go-to for doing the same with integers in string form. This is just a hypothesis, but `Double/parseDouble` might be faster and/or more accurate than `read-string` because it's optimized for doubles.

FYI, you can leave out the `java.lang.` and just call it as `Double/parseDouble` in your code. In light of that, you might consider getting rid of your `parse-double` function altogether and just using `Double/parseDouble` whenever you need it. The only thing is that Java methods aren't first-class in Clojure, so you would need to do things like this if you go that route:

```
(defn parse-row [line]
  (map #(Double/parseDouble %) (split line #"\s+")))
```

(Personally, I still like that better, but you might prefer to keep it wrapped in a function `parse-double` like you have it. It's up to you!)

I think needing to mess with the locale might be a locale-specific problem... I tried playing around with `(format "%.7f" ...` without changing my locale and it worked as expected. Granted, I'm in the US :)

I think the legibility issues you're seeing might be related to having too many functions. You might consider condensing and renaming things and see if you like that better. I would re-structure your program so that you parse the data into the data structure at the top, something like this:

```
(defn parse-test-cases [in-file]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader in-file)]
    (let [rows (rest (line-seq rdr))]
      (map (fn [row] 
             (map #(Double/parseDouble %) (split row #"\s+")))
           rows))))
```

(I condensed your functions `parse-row`, `parse-test-cases` and half of `spit-answers` into the function above)

Then define the functions that "do all the work" like `min-time`, and then, at the end:

```
(defn spit-answers [answers out-file]
  (with-open [w (io/writer out-file :append false)]
    (.write w (clojure.string/join "\n" answers)))

(def -main []
  (let [in  "resources/cookie_clicker/B-large-practice.in"
        out "resources/cookie_clicker/B-large-practice.out"
        test-cases (parse-test-cases in)
        answers (map-indexed (fn [i [c f x]]
                               (format "Case #%d: %.7f" (inc i) (min-time c f x)))
                             test-cases)]
    (spit-answers answers out)))
```

I came up with a few ideas above:

1. In your `answers` function you use `(map ... (rest (range)) (test-cases))` in order to number each case, starting from 1. A simpler way to do this is with `map-indexed`. I used `(inc i) for the case numbers`, since the index numbering starts at 0.
2. I condensed `(str "Case #" n ": " (format "%.7f" t)))` into a single call to `format`.
3. I used destructuring over the arguments to the `map-indexed` function to represent each case as `c f x` -- that way it's clearer that each test case consists of those three values, and you can represent the calculation as `(min-time c f x)` instead of `(apply min-time test-case)`.

As for your `min-time` function, I don't think `loop`/`recur` is necessarily a bad thing, and I often tend to rely on it in complicated situations where you're doing more involved work on each iteration, checking conditions, etc. I think it's OK to use it here. But if you want to go a more functional route, you could consider writing a `step` function and creating a lazy sequence of game states using `iterate`, like so:

(note: I'm writing `step` as a `letfn` binding so that it can use arbitrary values of `c`, `f` and `x` that you feed into a higher-order function that I'm calling `step-seq` -- this HOF takes values for `c`, `f` and `x` and generates a lazy sequence of game states or "steps.")

```
(defn step-seq [c f x]
  (letfn [(step [{:keys [factories time-cost cookie-rate total-time result]}]
            (let [new-time-cost (+ time-cost (/ c cookie-rate))
                  new-cookie-rate (+ cookie-rate f)
                  new-total-time (+ new-time-cost (/ x new-cookie-rate))]
              {:factories (inc factories)
               :time-cost new-time-cost
               :cookie-rate new-cookie-rate
               :total-time new-total-time
               :result (when (> new-total-time total-time) total-time)}))]
    (iterate step {:factories 0, :time-cost 0, :cookie-rate 2.0, 
                   :total-time (/ x 2.0), :result nil})))
```

Now, finding the solution is as simple as grabbing the `:result` value from the first step that has one:

```
(defn min-step [c f x]
  (some :result (step-seq c f x)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As for `spit-answers`, I'd thought writing answers of test cases one by one would reduce memory requirement, but after reading your answer I realize the memory burden of the `join` would probably would be on the order of KBs for the majority of cases (and possibly having multiple disk seeks could hurt performance more).